# tools suggestion for debugging network off topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked the following questions,
'I have been using wireshark, which is good for debugging layer2 and above. Can anyone recommend a tool for debugging Layer1 or PHY? Does it need to be a logic analyzer with xMII protocol decoder?'

Why is the discussion about debugging network off-topic?

Comment: "_Why is the discussion about debugging network off-topic?_ A big reason is that SE sites are explicitly _not_ discussion forums. We have chat for that, as I pointed out, and you have enough reputation for that. All product and resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for the main Q&A site.

Comment: @moderator there is a [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site in the stack exchange family

Answer (score 1):

FWIW you can ask for software suggestions on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)